# Fetch XML and optionSets

Tags: dynamics-365, fetchxml

basic question.  Am using Fetch XML builder in XRM.  How do I tell Fetch to return the optionset label instead of the numeric value?

I have tried everything.  I can see in the result set the name of the OptionSet item is "there":

```
<resultset morerecords="0" >
  <result>
    <est formattedvalue="4,337.50" >4337.5</est>
    <sector name="Sustainable Industrial" formattedvalue="100000000" >100000000</sector>
    <sector_new_nsectorname>Sustainable Industrial</sector_new_nsectorname>
  </result>
  <result>
    <est formattedvalue="3,216.00" >3216</est>
    <sector name="Renewable" formattedvalue="100000002" >100000002</sector>
    <sector_new_nsectorname>Renewable</sector_new_nsectorname>
  </result>
  <result>
    <est formattedvalue="2,329.25" >2329.25</est>
    <sector name="Environmental" formattedvalue="100000001" >100000001</sector>
    <sector_new_nsectorname>Environmental</sector_new_nsectorname>
  </result>
</resultset>
```

But the actual results I get in column view are:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the bottom left corner of the Results view, click Appearance - Friendly Names.

[image: Screenshot of FetchXML Builder]

Comment: More information and a dedicated forum for FetchXML Builder is available at https://fetchxmlbuilder.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you wanted to know how to display the OptionSet Label in the FetchXrmBuilder or actually get the value of the label using fetchXML in your code.

Unfortunately you cannot get the label value through manipulating the fetch. I am adding a sample JS code to get the label value for an OptionSet by making another fetch request to stringmap entity. I have used product(Entity) and producttypecode(OptionSet) as to display how you can get the corresponding label values in a single result set by manipulating the result set of 2 different fetch.

```
var finalProductList = [];
var optionSetValueDict = {};
var productResultSet = [];

function OnLoad(executionContext)
{
    RetrieveOptionSetValue();
    RetrieveProduct();
}

function CreateOptionSetDict(optionSetValueResultSet)
{
    optionSetValueResultSet.forEach(function (obj)
    {
        optionSetValueDict[obj.attributevalue] = obj.value;
    });
}

function CreateProductList(productResultSet)
{
    productResultSet.forEach(function (obj)
    {
        var finalProduct = {};
        finalProduct['producttypecode'] = obj.producttypecode;
        finalProduct['producttypecodevalue'] = optionSetValueDict[obj.producttypecode];
        finalProduct['productnumber'] = obj.productnumber;
        finalProductList.push(finalProduct);
    });
}

function RetrieveProduct()
{
    var results;
    var fetchXmlQuery = '<fetch top="50" ><entity name="product" ><attribute name="productnumber" /><attribute name="producttypecode" /></entity></fetch>';
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open(
        "GET",
    Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() +
        "/api/data/v9.0/products?fetchXml=" + encodeURIComponent(fetchXmlQuery),
    false);
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", 'odata.include-annotations="*"');
    req.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (this.readyState === 4)
        {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200)
            {
                var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                CreateProductList(results.value);
            }
            else
            {
                alert(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}

function RetrieveOptionSetValue()
{
    var fetchXmlQuery = '<fetch><entity name="stringmap" ><attribute name="attributevalue" /><attribute name="value" /><filter type="and" ><condition attribute="objecttypecodename" operator="eq" value="product" /><condition attribute="attributename" operator="eq" value="producttypecode" /></filter></entity></fetch>';
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open(
        "GET",
    Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() +
        "/api/data/v9.0/stringmaps?fetchXml=" + encodeURIComponent(fetchXmlQuery),
    false);
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", 'odata.include-annotations="*"');
    req.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (this.readyState === 4)
        {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200)
            {
                var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                CreateOptionSetDict(results.value);
            }
            else
            {
                alert(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
```

Hope it helps. If you are looking for a way to this in C#, please comment so.